# React callback function not working. Found a bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I create a total of 4 components in react

2 are man component and the remaining two are the child

**Component one**

```
class HsProfileCover extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imgSrc: this.props.img
    }

    this.onCoverImageSelect = this.onCoverImageSelect.bind(this);
  }



  onCoverImageSelect(srcB64DataCover) {  
    console.log("cover");
    this.setState({ imgSrc: srcB64DataCover })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hs_profile_cover">
        <div className="cover_outer">
          <HsProfileImgChangeButton onImageSelect={this.onCoverImageSelect} />
          <div className="cover_shadow"></div>
          <img className="img-fluid" src={this.state.imgSrc} alt={this.props.alt} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Component 2**

```
class HsProfileBoxThumbImg extends PureComponent { 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

          this.state = {
            imgSrc : this.props.img
          }

        this.onThumbImageSelect = this.onThumbImageSelect.bind(this);
    }



    onThumbImageSelect(srcB64DataThumb){    
    console.log("thumb");
    this.setState({imgSrc : srcB64DataThumb})
  }




  render () {
    return (
      <div className="hs_com_profile_thumb_img_box">
          <HsProfileImgChangeButton onImageSelect={this.onThumbImageSelect} />
          <img className="img-thumbnail" src={this.state.imgSrc} alt={this.props.alt}/>
      </div>
        
    );
  }
}
```

Both components have a child component **HsProfileImgChangeButton**

```
const  HsProfileImgChangeButton = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div className="hs_com_profile_img_change_button shadow">
      <HsSelectFileHelper {...props}  />        
       <div className="ed_outer">
            <button className="btn btn-link ed_inner">
                <i className="hs-i-edit"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
    </div>
      
  );
});


export default HsProfileImgChangeButton;
```

This child component calling **HsSelectFileHelper ** which do the file selection work

```
class HsSelectFileHelper extends PureComponent { 

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onSelectFile = this.onSelectFile.bind(this);
    }

    


    onSelectFile(e) {
          if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
            if(e.target.files.length===1){
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
                this.onImageSelect(reader.result )
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
            }else{
              this.onImagesSelect(e.target.files);
          }
        }
    }

    onImageSelect(srcB64Data){
      if(this.props.onImageSelect!==undefined && this.props.onImageSelect!==null){
        this.props.onImageSelect(srcB64Data);
      }
    }

    onImagesSelect(files){
      if(this.props.onImagesSelect!==undefined && this.props.onImagesSelect!==null){
        this.props.onImagesSelect(files);
      }
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="hs_select_image_helper">        
         <input type="file" className="sr-only d-none" id="avatar-change" onChange={this.onSelectFile} name="image" accept="image/*" />
         <label className="hs_img_select mb-0" htmlFor="avatar-change"></label>
      </div>
        
    );
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine.

**But**

Everything I call the callback function from the child. it calls the Colback from **HsProfileCover** and no matter what I do. it never calls the callback from **HsProfileBoxThumbImg**

am I doing something wrong or I found I bug?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think the "react community" is to blame. Are you sure this is all the relevant code? If it works for cover, it should work for thumb as well, but you provided `HsSelectFileHelper` instead of `HsProfileImgChangeButton` and there are a lot of formatting issues. Are you sure this is the real code you are working with which causes the issue?

Comment: @Narigo I just updated my question. sorry, I was just frustrated. from last 4 hours. I tried every signal combination but nothing is working. Both components calling the child component on the same page but the file always going to cover page because coverage calling it first

Comment: If suggest you create a CodePen or equivalent to demonstrate the issue, from the code it's not immediately obvious why it wouldn't work. Are you rendering both components on the form at the same time? If so, are you rendering the `HsProfileCover` component first by any chance?